# Anchor row data type variable from declare cursor

Tags: db2, cursor, anchor, procedure

How can I declare variable using anchor data type (row) from a declared cursor in db2?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE     "SP_ATUALIZA_ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_FT"
    BEGIN

        DECLARE C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS CURSOR FOR
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    F.ID_MES,
                    F.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO,
                    D.CNPJ_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO,
                    F.ID_COMPANIA
                FROM    
                    DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDAS_SELLOUT F,
                    DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_ECDISTRIBUIDOR_SO D
                WHERE ID_MES <= 201309 AND                                
                  F.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO = D.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO AND
                  F.ID_COMPANIA <> D.ID_COMPANIA
                ORDER BY ID_MES;
         BEGIN
         DECLARE REG_C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS ANCHOR ROW OF C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS;

         OPEN C_ID_DIST_ERADOS
         ...
         END;

    END;
```

I've a procedure that is declaring a internal cursor, which will be used to fetch results and insert into a variable 'reg_c_id_dist_errados'. I've tried to use "anchor row of" but db2 has alerted me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [anchor a type to a row](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053559.html) of a table , among other things. There are different ways to use these things depending on your requirements.

Your query has a join so you can declare a type to match each row from the cursor, and you can then declare strongly-typed cursor-type for your rowtype. Later you can assign a query to a variable of that cursor-type.

You can pass cursors as parameters to stored procedures, and you can have a procedure return a cursor type, and you can declare variables of each of the types you create.

You don't show whether you want the result-set of the procedure to be a cursor-type, or whether you want to process the result-set inside the stored-procedure in typed variables.

Study the Db2 Knowledge Centre for your version of Db2-LUW to learn about strongly typed cursors and how to use them in SQL PL.

There is an example online (shown as a module, but you can use the same techniques in a stored procedures) in this file "modules.db2" which also appears under the SAMPLES directory on your DB2-LUW server if you installed the samples component at installation time.

You can see the example online at 
[the example modules.sql](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/sqlpl/s-modules-db2.html)

Here is one suggestion for using user defined types for a row-type that matches the cursor in your code:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @


-- this type represents a row that might be returned in the cursor. 
-- Choose your own name for the type.
-- Choose the correct data-types for your tables.

create or replace type DE_ROW_T as row
(
id_mes bigint,
ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO bigint,
CNPJ_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO bigint,
ID_COMPANIA bigint
)@



create or replace type C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS_CURSOR_T as DE_ROW_T CURSOR@

create or replace PROCEDURE     "SP_ATUALIZA_ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_FT"
language sql
specific SP_ATUALIZA_ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_FT
    BEGIN

        DECLARE V_ROW DE_ROW_T;
        DECLARE C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS  C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS_CURSOR_T;


        SET C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS = CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    F.ID_MES,
                    F.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO,
                    D.CNPJ_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO,
                    F.ID_COMPANIA
                FROM    
                    DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDAS_SELLOUT F,
                    DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_ECDISTRIBUIDOR_SO D
                WHERE ID_MES <= 201309 AND                                
                  F.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO = D.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR_SO AND
                  F.ID_COMPANIA <> D.ID_COMPANIA
                ORDER BY ID_MES;

         OPEN C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS;
         FETCH C_ID_DIST_ERRADOS INTO v_row;

    END@
```